# Why does division become faster with very large numbers

Tags: python, time, time-complexity, bignum

I wanted to see how constant the division operation is, so I ran this code

```
import time

def di(n):
    n/101

i = 10
while i < 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:
    start = time.clock()
    di(i)
    end = time.clock()
    print("On " + str(i) + " " + str(end-start))
    i *= 10000
```

And this was the output I got

```
On 10 5.98714047756e-06
On 100000 4.7041818038e-06
On 1000000000 2.56591734753e-06
On 10000000000000 2.99357023878e-06
On 100000000000000000 2.99357023878e-06
On 1000000000000000000000 2.99357023879e-06
On 10000000000000000000000000 2.99357023878e-06
On 100000000000000000000000000000 3.42122313003e-06
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000 3.42122313003e-06
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000 3.84887602128e-06
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000 3.42122313003e-06
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 3.84887602128e-06
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.71061156501e-06
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.71061156502e-06
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.71061156501e-06
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 2.13826445628e-06
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.71061156502e-06
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 2.13826445628e-06
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 2.13826445628e-06
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 2.13826445626e-06
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 2.13826445626e-06
```

Why does the division generally get faster later on as opposed to the time of the first two terms which are the smallest?

Comment: I would run it a second time just to make sure it's not a fluke, as those times are small enough to vary with system load. Also should note that integer division is probably more efficient than floating point division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the division generally get faster later on as opposed to the time of the first two terms which are the smallest?

It doesn't, actually. If I replace `di` with:

```
def di(n):
    for i in range(10000000): n / 101
```

Then I get (Python 3.5, which I presume you are using):

```
On 10 0.546889
On 100000 0.545004
On 1000000000 0.5454929999999998
On 10000000000000 0.5519709999999998
On 100000000000000000 1.330797
On 1000000000000000000000 1.31053
On 10000000000000000000000000 1.3393129999999998
On 100000000000000000000000000000 1.3524339999999997
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000 1.3817269999999997
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.3412670000000002
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.3358929999999987
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.3773859999999996
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.3326890000000002
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.3704769999999993
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.3235019999999995
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.357647
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.3341190000000012
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.326544000000002
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.3671139999999973
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.3630120000000012
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.3600200000000022
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.3189189999999975
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1.3503469999999993
```

As you can see, there are roughly two times: one for smaller numbers, and one for larger numbers. In Python 3.5, `/` does floating point division, so it should actually take about the same amount of time regardless of the size of the numbers.

However, there is that gap from small to large. The same result happens with Python 2.7 using the following function to preserve semantics:

```
def di(n):
    for i in xrange(10000000): n / 101.0
```

On the same machine, I get:

```
On 10 0.617427
On 100000 0.61805
On 1000000000 0.6366
On 10000000000000 0.620919
On 100000000000000000 0.616695
On 1000000000000000000000 0.927353
On 10000000000000000000000000 1.007156
On 100000000000000000000000000000 0.98597
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000 0.99258
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.966753
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.992684
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.991711
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.994703
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.978877
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.982035
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.973266
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.977911
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.996857
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.972555
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.985676
On 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.987412
On 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.997207
On 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 0.970129
```

This has something to do (exact specifics to be determined) with converting the integer to a floating point number. This is slower with integers beyond a certain point, and when that point is crossed, the division starts taking longer.

Comment: For Python 2.7 use `xrange` instead of `range` to make them equivalent.  Right now in Python 2.7 you are allocating a giant array and iterating over it instead of generating the numbers on demand.

Comment: @JakeCobb: Aye I just caught that =). Now the small number times are comparable, although Python 2.7 still gets slower as the numbers get larger.

Comment: Probably because the smaller numbers use different storage behind the scenes.  In 2.7, `type(10)` is `<type 'int'>` but `type(1000000000000000000000)` is `<type 'long'>`

Comment: In Python 3 the time **doesn't** increase after it reaches ~1.3 seconds early on. Why should it? Conversion to float and then the float division are probably both constant time.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Oops, I forgot that Python 3's `/` is different than Python 2's. Will update

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Fixed it... I'm not sure how to explain the two different timings, though. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Claudiu With finer analysis, multiplying with 2 instead of 10000, you'll likely find that the jump occurs around 2**53. Which suggests it has to do with the mantissa of floats storing 53 bits.

Comment: @Claudiu Not sure how it's done exactly, but I'm guessing if the number is small, Python just lets the hardware convert to float, and when it's larger, it builds the float itself by taking the top 53 bits, the bit length and the sign? That's btw also why I think conversion to float ought to be constant time, as it can just ignore everything after the top 53 bits.

Comment: @Claudiu Can you please post the code producing the last part with 2^1 to 2^69?

Answer (score 1):

"Division generally gets faster" is not an accurate description of your observations.  It looks like they get faster, then slower, then faster, then slower, then faster, then slower, then faster.  I tried two modifications to your script:

1. Inside the while loop, instead of just calling `di` once, call it `10` times and print out the min, max, and mean times.  I found the max times show roughly the pattern you're seeing, and that the min times were 0.0, so perhaps the interpreter is caching the result of the function call as an optimization.
2. Reversed the order of the inputs, so starting at a big number for `i` and going down each time `i /= 10000`.  The max times showed a similar pattern here, in that the first few calculations took more time than the rest.  That is, whatever calculation was done first seemed to take more time, didn't matter whether it was the program that started with small numbers, or the one that started with large numbers.